# Issue writing MySQL query to find difference

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with sorting out a query for the following:

```
Data:
Column1  Column2
2        0
0        -2
```

I'm trying to select the difference between Column1 and Column2, with a minimum of 0. Eg.

```
Row1=2
Row2=0
```

My current query is `SELECT (Column1 - Column2) as total FROM blah`.

I tried adding `max(Column2, 0)` into the query, but that just errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 SELECT GREATEST(Column1 - Column2, 0)
 from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL function `MAX()` is an aggregate function, often used in combination with a `GROUP BY`. It only takes one argument (the name of the column of which you want to select the maximum value). The `GREATEST()` function is the function you need (as Michael Pakhantsov pointed out).